# Issues with very basic scrollbar not acting as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to make a div that moves up and down the page depending on how much has been scrolled. I use `scrollTop` to return the top value of the browser's scrollbar, and set my div to that position. However, I'm getting some funny results, and my div is jumping all around the page when I scroll. Can anyone help me figure out why?

HTML

```
<body id="body">
    <div id="scrollBar"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
$(window).mousewheel(function(turn, delta) {

  if (delta == 1) // going down

    document.getElementById("scrollBar").style.top = $("body").scrollTop() + "px";

  else //going up

  document.getElementById("scrollBar").style.top = $("body").scrollTop() + "px";

});
```

CSS

```
#scrollBar {
    position:relative;
    right:0px;
    width: 5px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:2000;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: try `$(window).on('scroll', function(){ //your code });` and when it may just work with body, try `$(this).scrollTop()` or `$(window).scrollTop()` if it doesn't. I recently used those for background parallax effect. Also try absolute positioning, top won't work with relative.

Comment: The solution you suggested doesn't seem to work, and the div just jitters about in one position - window or this doesn't seem to make a difference, either. What solution did you use for your parallax scrolling?

Comment: I might understand your question wrong, and I think I get it now, you want to rectangle appear on the bottom when page is scrolled all the way down, and at top when page is not scrolled down at all, right? Seems like you're trying to make div appear like scrollbar, but it won't be able to scroll by mouse clicks, just show the position.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I intent to do. You couldn't have said it more accurately.

Comment: @Mr_KoKa Forgot to tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get what you're trying to do:

First you need to calculate the scrollbar's height. You could do this by using:

`window.innerHeight * (window.innerHeight / document.body.offsetHeight)`

Then use `$.scroll()` and put your logic inside it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var brwserSBHeight =  window.innerHeight * (window.innerHeight / document.body.offsetHeight) +"px"
    document.getElementById("scrollBar").style.height = brwserSBHeight ; 

    $(window).on('scroll',function(e){
        document.getElementById("scrollBar").style.top = $(window).scrollTop() + "px";
       document.getElementById("scrollBar").style.top = $(window).scrollTop() + "px";

})
```

And, change the `position:fixed` in css:

[***Demo***](https://plnkr.co/edit/5Izjyf0gpvkRBKXYBb04?p=preview)

Comment: The problem with having the scrollBar's position:fixed is that when you scroll to the very bottom of the form you have provided the scrollbar goes to far under the page. If the form was to be, say, three times as long, the scrollbar would go so far and eventually disappear before you have reached the bottom. I'll try put a jsfiddle together to demonstrate.

Comment: Did you get the fiddle

Comment: @CasparB you need to convert 'px' to '%'. Look at: https://jsfiddle.net/o6eaqn0v/1/

Answer (score 0):

I came up with some thing similar, but with absolute positioning:

```js
var scrollBar = $('#scrollBar');
var jqWindow = $(window);
var jqDocument = $(document);

jqWindow.on('scroll resize load', function(e){
  var windowHeight = jqWindow.height();
  var pageHeight = jqDocument.height();
  
  if(pageHeight === 0 || pageHeight - windowHeight === 0){
    return;
  }
  
  var scroll = jqWindow.scrollTop();
  var notVisiblePageScrollRatio = scroll / (pageHeight - windowHeight);
  
  var scrollBarHeight = windowHeight * (windowHeight / pageHeight);
  var scrollBarPosition = (pageHeight - scrollBarHeight) * notVisiblePageScrollRatio;
  scrollBar.height(scrollBarHeight);
  scrollBar.css('top', scrollBarPosition);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

#scrollBar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; /*calculated by js*/
  right: 100px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 0; /*calculated by js*/
  background: #000;
}

#scrollBar:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #FF0;
}

#scrollBar:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="scrollBar"></div>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
    Some content 1<br/>Some content 2<br/>Some content 3<br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was also thinking about checking for pageHeight be less than window height so you can hide you'r scrollbar when it is not needed, but I had some troubles with resize event not firing up past certain window height, so it was clunky and last reported heights of window and page were different one or two, when at the end they were at least equal, I was checking it by setting interval that was reporting those heights. So I don't include that functionality here, but I think it is something that may come handy.

Comment: Have a look at this. Note the issue where the scrollbar shoots off the page.